# MS Word and document Advanced Properties

Tags: ms-office

Where can I find document Advanced Properties on Word (ver 15) for Mac?

There is no such of option like File->Properties

[image]

On a PC version is under

> Files -> Options -> Quick Access Toolbar -> All Commands -> Advanced
>   Document Properties

but in Mac version I don't see that kind of a command in "All Commands" options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Office 2016 for Mac, it's File > Properties.

[image]

This window is nearly identical to the window in the link.
[image: Window]